# Attached Dependency Property

Tags: android, design-patterns

I have just under two months developing with android and I think a great tool, now I've started my project to extend some views to add new features (Example: use custom fonts), but I have a question, there is a WPF functionality (. NET framework) that is really useful at times like this, without extending classes.

This is known as [Attached Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx), basically is the ability to add a new property to an existing class.

#### Normal Android example

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:my="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.package.custom"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.package.CustomTextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:text="@string/hello" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
        android:textColor="@colors/text_color"
        my:fontface="fonts/my-custom-font.ttf"
        my:autosize="true"/>

    <com.package.CustomButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_continue"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/text_btn"
        my:fontface="fonts/my-custom-btn-font.ttf" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

regularly to add features like that would have to extend the TextView class but with Attached Property whe can do this

#### Attached property example

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:my="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.package.custom"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- there is no need to extend the class -->
    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:text="@string/hello" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
        android:textColor="@colors/text_color"
        my:fontface="fonts/my-custom-font.ttf"
        my:autosize="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_continue"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/text_btn"
        my:fontface="fonts/my-custom-btn-font.ttf" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

this save a lot of work becouse we could use not only with TextView also with others classes

Comment: The document that you link to "assumes that you understand dependency properties from the perspective of a consumer of existing dependency properties on Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) classes, and have read the Dependency Properties Overview". Since the overlap betweeen WPF developers and Android developers is modest, you might consider editing your question to explain what an "attached property" is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but you cannot invent new attributes for use with existing classes and use the standard inflation mechanism. For starters, there is no place for that data to be stored on a `View`.

That being said, there is nothing stopping you from using the syntax in the second XML block. It's just that `LayoutInflater` will ignore the unrecognized stuff (and the build tools might grumble). You could:

- Try to clone `LayoutInflater` into your own app and augment it with additional capabilities related to your custom attributes, or
- Load the layout XML yourself from `Resources` into an `XmlResourceParser`, walk it to find all of your custom attributes, and apply them to the widgets inflated by a regular `LayoutInflater`

The latter, while more cumbersome, may be easier to achieve (`LayoutInflater` may have lots of dependencies outside of the SDK) and should be easier to maintain (`LayoutInflater` may change over time, requiring re-ports).

Comment: I also thought about cloning the LayoutInflater but better think of something else, because it's true that you can lose all that work when it comes out in a new version of android